# is it possible to install matlab on an external hdd and use it with any computer?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a portable solution to using matlab on any computer.I tried to install matlab on the hdd and found that it wouldn't work on other computers. What can I do to make it work? Is it even possible?

Comment: I think it is impossible. Just think that if Matlab developer allow this, then someone could create a flash drive with a licensed software and share to anyone to copy. Than anyone else would need to buy another license anymore.

Comment: It is possible, but I think it is illegal... Try to use an existing portable free solution, like Scilab portable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are part of a large organization that can justify the cost of a concurrent licence, then no, it's not possible

*A Concurrent license enables you to make MathWorks products available to anyone with access to your network*